# php mysql_fetch_array query help

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm trying to process the mysql_fetch_array query below and simplify the code so only 1 query is ran for both sets, is that possible

```
<select name=[set1]>    
<?php
$set1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `Locale` FROM `language` WHERE `Setting` = '1' ORDER BY FormatSet"));
while($row = $set1){
    echo "<option value=\"$set1\">$set1</option>\n";
}
?>
                </select>
                <select name=[set2]>    
<?php
$set2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `Locale` FROM `language` WHERE `Setting` = '2' ORDER BY FormatSet"));
while($row = $set2){
    echo "<option value=\"$set2\">$set2</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: That code shouldn't even run. The while-loop will run forever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$textSet1 = '<select name=[set1]>';
$textSet2 = '<select name=[set2]>';
$set = mysql_query("SELECT `Locale`, `Setting` FROM `language` WHERE `Setting` in ('1','2') ORDER BY FormatSet");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($set)){
    if ($row['Setting'] == '1')
         $textSet1 .= '<option value="'.$row['Locale'].'">'.$row['Locale'].'</option>';
    else
         $textSet2 .= '<option value="'.$row['Locale'].'">'.$row['Locale'].'</option>';
}
$textSet1 .= '</select>';
$textSet2 .= '</select>';

echo $textSet1;
echo $textSet2;
?>
```

Comment: The condition should be: `while($row = mysq_fetch_array($set))` whith `$set= mysql_query(...`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that both part dropdown boxes must show. would the could above allow that? I'm not able to test yet but I'm noticing the condition statement

Comment: Yes, both of them will show. The condition is to put each result in the corresponding select. At the end there are the 2 echo lines.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question you want to perform both queries at once and half your code.

I'd suggest changing your query to get all the records in one go, and use a flag to create a new select for each new setting, this should work and can easily have more settings added:

```
$set = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `Locale` FROM `language` WHERE `Setting` = '1' OR 'Setting' = '2' ORDER BY Setting, FormatSet"));

$setting = 0;
$close = false;

foreach ($set as $row)
{
    if ($row['Setting'] > $setting)
    {
        $setting = $row['Setting'];
        echo "<select name=[set{$setting}]>";
        // Set flag to close select
        $close = true;
    }

    echo "<option value=\"{$row['Locale']}\">{$row['Locale']}</option>\n";

    if ($close)
    {
        echo '</select>';
        $close = false;
    }
}
```